# PHP Script changing URL structure in all directories

Tags: php, database, url

I was just given access to a development server. I created a directory in the public_html folder called "test-site". When I visit http://developmentdomain.com/test-site/ the URL string becomes: http://developmentdomain.com/test-site/?p=test-site

The reason this is happening is because index.php in the root directory is telling all sub directories to add this on the end of the URL. The main site (hosted in the root) needs this file, but I do not want all of the other sub directories to be affected by it. How would I change the following code so it only applies to the root, bot not sub directories? This line is what is causing it:  `$p = ($_REQUEST['p'] != '' ? $_REQUEST['p'] : 'home');`

CODE:

```
<?
session_start();
$_SESSION['bj'] = 1;
include "db.php";
require_once("classes/layout.class.php");
require_once("classes/content.class.php");
$p = ($_REQUEST['p'] != '' ? $_REQUEST['p'] : 'home');

$layout = new layout();
$layout->startPage($p);
$layout->buildHead($p);
$layout->buildBody($p);

$content = new content();
$content->buildHeader($p);
$content->buildLogoNav($p);
$content->buildPage($p);
$content->buildFooter($p);

$layout->closePage($p);
?>
```

Comment: above code is complete index.php file in the root

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the $_GET parameter is being used as a custom CMS.

1. Check any rewrite rules.
2. Review the layout() class
3. Review your server-side includes `classes/layout.class.php` & `classes/content.class.php`

The URL is being modified at some point programatically.  Assuming its not a problem due to #1, then keep an eye out for a portion of code that manipulates the [header()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php), i.e. `header('Location: some/new/location');`

Comment: Yes, thanks for your answer. It is indeed a custom CMS, but the organization is real messy. I am going to dig around and see what I can find.

Comment: There is nothing in the classes directory that is changing the URL, must be some rewrite rules.

Comment: Does this seem to be the culprit: RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)$ /index.php?p=$1

Comment: That is manipulating the URL but the 'ags' would have to be found in the URL you provide in order for it to be affected by that rule. The rules attempts to take any combination of alpha-numeric characters, including '_' & '-', and rewrite it to index.php?p=YOUR_CHARACTERS, which is handled by the code you posted in your question.

Comment: yes, Understood. I actually mistyped in my above answer (see updated post). This did fix it. thanks for pointing me in the right direction!